# CFHeader / CFContent does not display download dialog for Word Document / IE9

Tags: coldfusion, internet-explorer-9, coldfusion-9

This is my first time posting to Stack Overflow, so be gentle. We are on CF9 with IE9, using `coldbox 2.6.3` as our framework. The code was written for `CF8 IE8`, and everything works just fine. However, when I run the same code in `IE9` on `CF9`, it does not work.

So, we have a popup box that allows a user to add some information. From that information, the handler function will manipulate that data, and use this logic to display the download dialog box for a Word document: (sorry if format is bad, first time)

```
<cfsavecontent variable="LetterContent">
    <cfoutput>#evaluate(DE(rc.correspondenceTemplate.EMAIL_BOILER_LETTER))#</cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>

<cfset temp = iSxs.InsCaseEvent(#rc.CaseID#,#currentAppID#,#variables.form_id#,#rc.eventTypeID#)>

<cfset rc.whichView = "correspondence/vwPopupNewEmailLetter&loadAction=correspondenceComplete">

<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=#docTitle#" />
<cfcontent type="application/msword" reset="yes" variable="#ToBinary(ToBase64(LetterContent))#"  />
```

Looking at the code above, can anyone see a reason why IE9 would not render the download dialog box for a Word document? Is the syntax of this code correct for IE9 / CF9, compared to CF8/IE8, or did something change and I just have not updated the code?

Thanks for being kind and hope someone sees something I missed.

Comment: Sounds like IE9's problem. does the file just open in word or does it not do anything? Keep in mind IE9's dialog box is a yellow bar at the bottom of the window and not the traditional pop up dialog (I can't remember if it was that way in 8, I avoid using IE as much as I can).

Comment: The only thing I see that bothers me right away is the evaluate function (it's icky) and all the pound signs `<cfset temp = iSxs.InsCaseEvent(#rc.CaseID#,#currentAppID#,#variables.form_id#,#rc.eventTypeID#)>` should be just `<cfset temp = iSxs.InsCaseEvent(rc.CaseID,currentAppID,variables.form_id,rc.eventTypeID)>`

Comment: Travis, I am thinking it is an IE9 issue as well. I can get this to work in FF, but not IE9. I have used a basic example from Ben N's blog, and the same thing happens with his code, but his cfcontent is just some static text. I have a feeling the issue is in the CFHeader and how it is working with IE9...any thoughts from you or anyone else?

Comment: I think you should try static text in your cfcontent tag and see if that works.

Comment: I used some Ben Nadel test code to check this, and his code used static text in the cfsavecontent, used a static filename, and still used toBinary and Tobase64 around the cfsavecontent name in the cfcontent tag, but still no download box...i have tested other spots in our code that uses this same syntax, and it does not work in IE9 either...no download box for a word doc, or an excel file, but works in IE8/CF8.

Comment: The following minimal version of your code is working for me in IE9
`<cfsavecontent variable="LetterContent">TEST</cfsavecontent>
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename""test.doc"""/>
<cfcontent type="application/msword" reset="yes" variable="#ToBinary( ToBase64( LetterContent ) )#"/>`

Comment: CFSimplicity, did you change any settings in IE9, or are you running the stock IE9? I have not changed anything in IE9 since it was installed, but I take your code, and I get nothing, just a blank screen, no download dialog box, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a different content type, this should work for .docx files.

```
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" reset="yes" variable="#ToBinary(ToBase64(LetterContent))#"  >
```

I think its worth a shot.